# Location of the Blob Store using SAS

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am looking for a REST API using which my application can determine the location of the Blob Storage account. The application has an access to a specific blob using the Shared Access Signature.

Comment: Did u have a read into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs

Comment: What language are you using? Why existing SDKs are not enough?

Comment: Please provide sample input

Comment: .NET SDK [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#list-the-blobs-in-a-container) retrieving `blob.Uri`. You can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to intercept what REST API call it makes underneath.

Comment: I went through the REST APIs I did see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/StorageAccounts/GetProperties , which could get the location of the Storage Account. However in this case the application doesn't have details of the underlying storage account hence parameters like resource manager name aren't available. The application doesn't have the full access to azure subscription , it just has access to the blob using SAS signatures

Comment: Unless you have access to Azure Subscription, it will not be possible for you to find the location of storage account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just have a blob's SAS URL, then you will not be able to find the location of the storage account.

In order to get the location of a storage account, you would need to use is [`Storage Resource Provider API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/) especially [`Storage Accounts - Get Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/getproperties) operation there. When you perform this operation, the location of the storage account is available in `primaryLocation` attribute in response. In order to perform this operation, you would need access to underlying Azure Subscription.

Using [`Storage REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices) it is not possible to find this information currently. This API enables you to manage the data in a storage account.